# SAP UI5 export table with charts

Tags: csv, charts, sapui5

I am working in SAP UI 5 and right now we are exporting a table in csv format and we have some charts in our app and i have to export the table with the charts as well.

This is my code for simple csv export

```
var oExport = new sap.ui.core.util.Export({
exportType: new sap.ui.core.util.ExportTypeCSV({
    separatorChar: ";",
    charSet: "UTF-8",
}),
models: oModel,

rows: {
    path: "/" 
},
columns: {...});
```

The best suggestion i have found was downloading the csv with pictures of charts in zip, but this is not what i am looking for, somehow i need a .xls file and i have to hack charts into it with the table as well.

Comment: Just wondering, how would you have expected the charts to magically appear in an XLS file? ;-) The only sane way i see it is you need to use a server-side library to generate your XLS file

Comment: There are some javascript excel libraries out there. But then you will get an other problem: You are not allowed to open a save dialog out of javascript. The data has to come from the server with a appropriate mime type to open a save dialog (or Excel inside of the browser).